# single sign on best approach advice

Tags: php, .net, mysql, sql

I need some advice on the best approach for a single sign on solution.

Basically I am dealing with 2 sites already in production. Site A is .net paiedr with SQL, while site B is php paired with MySQL.

I figure a quick and dirty way to create a single login, would be to import existing users from site A into site B and vice versa. Then I would add some additional code to the registration script so if a new member registers in site A, the new account will be inserted into both database going forward. The same for site B.

I would appreciate alternate suggestions.. Thanks

Comment: Are these physically separate sites?

Comment: @Glenn, Yes. He mentioned Site A and Site B.

Answer (score 1):

Why two sites BTW ?? 
Can't you integrate to a single site ?

Effective Solution is..

Choose either one solution .Net or PHP , Because to keep track of each and every action of the user , your script will be executing on both sites for a single user action. That is not considered to be efficient., as this is an unneccesary load. So either sacrifice .Net or PHP.

Redirect siteA url to siteB or vice-versa (depending on your solution)

Get a good hosting solution from MT (MediaTemple) {am not advertising btw ;)} such that it can manage/balance traffic that was receiving on both the sites.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking you dont want to have to maintain 2 datasets, at any given point they will get out of sync when an error on your application or the network occurs, best case scenario will be to map Site A users with Site B, and have a service between them like an API ( make sure you use SSL ), you will have to decide which of the sites will host the user data.

If you decide on Site A then:

If user on Site B registers and creates a new account, Site B sends that data to Site A, Site A saves to the DB and responds with success to Site B, User is now registered

User on Site B tries to log in, Site B sends user details to Site A, on success you will now be logged in

This is the approach i would use.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you can just connect Site A to Site B's SQL database, and Visa-versa so you only need to really use 1 database of the two sites.

To insert into two different databases, just connect to each database, one at a time, and execute your query. For example:

```
$mysql1 = array (
    'host' => 'host1.website.com',
    'username' => 'host1_username',
    'password' => 'host1_password',
    'database' => 'host1_database'
);
$mysql2 = array (
    'host' => 'host2.website.com',
    'username' => 'host2_username',
    'password' => 'host2_password',
    'database' => 'host2_database'
);

//insert into database 1
$connection = mysql_connect($mysql1['host'],$mysql1['username'],$mysql1['password']);
if($connection) { if(mysql_select_db($mysql1['database'])) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO `tablename` VALUES ('blah','blah','blah!');
    if(mysql_query($query)) {
        echo "Success in Database 1!";
    } else {
        echo "Failure in Database 1.";
    }
} }

//insert into database 2
$connection = mysql_connect($mysql2['host'],$mysql2['username'],$mysql2['password']);
if($connection) { if(mysql_select_db($mysql2['database'])) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO `tablename` VALUES ('blah','blah','blah!');
    if(mysql_query($query)) {
        echo "Success in Database 2!";
    } else {
        echo "Failure in Database 2.";
    }
} }
```

But I suggest only using 1 database and making both websites connect to the 1 database.